# TableViewController Image Sizing Swift 4 Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Alright, so I'm building a weather app that has an extended forecast page, which is just a TableViewController that has data passed into it from JSON data I am parsing. My problem is the data has an icon image it passes into the table view cell, which I am accounting for, but for some reason the first few icons size very large. When I scroll down the page and then back up the images have been properly sized.

I'd upload screenshots, but StackOverflow isn't letting me for some reason...
Thanks for the help.

Comment: [Edit] your question to include relevant code, as text.

Comment: Are you running your app one the iPhone X?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear but give a fixed width and height as the autolayout constraint.